# Android BroadcastReceiver won't register

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to add a simple broadcast receiver to my audio application, so that I can mute everything when the user clicks their ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON on their headset.  I've read that you can either register it in the manifest, or dynamically in the code.  I have gone down the path of registering it in the code, as I need to call methods within my main activity class to react to the media button press.  For some reason however, my BroadcastReceiver just will not register, and I can't find anything that explains why (grey hairs increasing).

The following is what I have in MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  public IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);

  public BroadcastReceiver MediaButtonIntentReceiver =
            new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    String intentAction = intent.getAction();
                    if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
                        KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent) intent
                                .getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
                        int action = event.getAction();
                        if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                            Log.e("INFO", "Media Button Pressed");
                            MuteAll();

                        }


                }
           }
  };

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       

      // Register media button event receiver
      intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON");
      intentFilter.setPriority(10000);
      this.registerReceiver(MediaButtonIntentReceiver, intentFilter);

      }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    // Unregister media button event receiver
    unregisterReceiver(MediaButtonIntentReceiver);

    }
};
```

I am certain that the BroadcastReceiver doesn't register, as wrapping the register as below gives me a toast confirming it is null:

```
  if (registerReceiver(MediaButtonIntentReceiver, intentFilter) == null) 
  {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Could not register receiver", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } else {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Receiver registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

EDIT:
I've also tried the following based on suggestions so far:

Reading through - http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html
I tried registering my receiver within the manifest like so...

```
<receiver android:name="com.mydomain.myapp.MainActivity$MediaButtonIntentReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

And then added the following example code:
public AudioManager am = mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
...
// Start listening for button presses
am.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(RemoteControlReceiver);
```

Eclipse complained that mContext didn't resolve to anything, so I added the following:

```
private Context mContext;
```

Then it complained about the "mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)" portion, saying "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to AudioManager"

So I added a cast to AudioManager:

```
public AudioManager am = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

And then added the suggested receiver registration code:

```
am.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(MediaButtonIntentReceiver);
```

To which it complained about "registerMediaButtonEventReceiver" saying "The method registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(ComponentName) in the type AudioManager is not applicable for the arguments (BroadcastReceiver)"

Clearly I'm doing something wrong here.  I've entered their example code as shown, yet it doesn't even compile.

--- END EDIT -----------------------------

Hoping someone out there can please help me.  Please let me know if I need to supply anything further.

Comment: As the `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` broadcast is not a sticky Intent, `registerReceiver()` will return null. Have you consulted this page? http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yeah I read that page through the many others, but I my lack of understanding of the way BroadcastReceivers and Intents seems to be my biggest problem.

Comment: Hi Mike, I've edited my original post to include the output of my attempts to follow the examples in the link you suggested.  Any ideas?

Comment: Well, the main problem at the moment is that you're trying to register an instance of MediaButtonIntentReceiver, but it's expecting just the class. Make MediaButtonIntentReceiver a class that `extends BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Also, get rid of the `mContext` declaration, and use `this.getSystemService()`, or just `getSystemService()`, as it's in an Activity Context.

Comment: Let me know if you've any more problems. I got it to compile, but, as I said in the comment I deleted, I have no device to test this with.

Comment: I should point out, to get this to work, I had to use `new ComponentName(this, MediaButtonIntentReceiver.class)` instead of just `MediaButtonIntentReceiver` when registering it.

Comment: Thanks heaps, we seem to be making progress, however it's still not quite there.  I changed my broadcast receiver to a class that extends BroadcastReceiver.  Then I replaced mContext as suggested.  I then found it complained that I was declaring my AudioManager and attempting to access system services before onCreate.  So I moved it into onCreate.  I updated my register and deregisters also as suggested to point to the class.

It now throws a Dalvik exception when I press my Media Button during runtime:

08-05 23:40:07.400: D/dalvikvm(32209): newInstance failed: no <init>()

Comment: Ok, that looks like it's expecting a constructor for the BroadcastReceiver. Try adding `public MediaButtonIntentReceiver(){}` in the Receiver class.

Comment: Oh, I lied! I _do_ have a device to test with, even though it's just a single-button control headset. Anyway, I got it to compile, run, and successfully receive the button click. So, yeah, lemme know if you've any further issues.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go tomorrow. Do I vote up your responses to turn them into answers? Still new to StackExchange :S

Comment: Comment upvotes don't really do anything, other than signify that someone agrees with you. I'll eventually get an answer typed up and formatted, to summarize what we did. But there's no rush. I'll make sure it's posted by tomorrow. Thanks! Hope we get you workin'!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Receiver for the `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` action should be registered with `AudioManager`'s `registerMediaButtonEventReceiver()` method, instead of the regular `registerReceiver()` method in the `Activity`. Unlike normal dynamic Receiver registration, however, this method takes the class as the parameter, instead of an instance of the class. The easiest way to this is to create a separate class file for it:

```
public class MediaButtonIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And we would need this Receiver listed in the manifest, as well:

```
<receiver android:name=".MediaButtonIntentReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Now, the example in the link we've referred to is wrong, as the `registerMediaButtonEventReceiver()` method is expecting a `ComponentName` object, not just the name of the Receiver class itself. We need to change the example as follows:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(
    new ComponentName(this, MediaButtonIntentReceiver.class));
```

And, as we've established, you don't need the `mContext` field, as you are in an`Activity` Context, and can just use `getSystemService()` without qualification. You can also do away with the `IntentFilter` object, as the listing in the manifest takes care of that already.