# How to get action from key of Headset in android

Tags: java, android, receiver

I am a android developer.I make a music player application.Now I want to handle play and pause event by headset.this is my code for register receiver:

```
IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    iF.setPriority(10000);
    registerReceiver(mButtonReceiver, iF);
```

and then get action in receiver class.
but not working.
please help me!!

Comment: A Receiver for the media buttons needs to be registered with `AudioManager`, instead of the usual way of registering Receivers. Check the [developer page](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html#PlaybackControls) for an example, and [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25158635) for corrections.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,solved problem.